# How can i save multiple labels and textboxes (9 labels and 9 texboxes) as .txt using SaveFileDialog?

Tags: vb.net, save

How can i save multiple labels and textboxes (9 labels and 9 texboxes) as .txt using SaveFileDialog? I tried a lot of ways but nothing works as i want .. i need to save them to .txt file every time the user's input and he choose where he want to save it .. I'm using Visual Basic 2008

this is my last try:

Try
        Dim dlg As SaveFileDialog = New SaveFileDialog
        dlg.Title = "Save"
        dlg.Filter = "Text Files(*.txt)|*.txt|All Files(*.*)|*.*|Rich Text Files (*.rtf)|*.rtf"
        If dlg.ShowDialog() = System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then
        My.Computer.FileSystem.WriteAllText("c:\value1.txt", Label1.Text & TextBox13.Text & Label2.Text & TextBox12.Text & Label3.Text & TextBox14.Text & Label4.Text & TextBox3.Text & Label5.Text & TextBox6.Text & Label6.Text & TextBox7.Text & Label7.Text & TextBox8.Text & Label8.Text & TextBox9.Text & Label9.Text & TextBox10.Text, False)
         End If
        Catch ex As Exception : End Try

Comment: Please show what have you tried so far

Comment: Try
        Dim dlg As SaveFileDialog = New SaveFileDialog
        dlg.Title = "Save"
        dlg.Filter = "Text Files(*.txt)|*.txt|All Files(*.*)|*.*|Rich Text Files (*.rtf)|*.rtf"
        If dlg.ShowDialog() = System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then
        My.Computer.FileSystem.WriteAllText("c:\value1.txt", Label1.Text & TextBox13.Text & Label2.Text & TextBox12.Text & Label3.Text & TextBox14.Text & Label4.Text & TextBox3.Text & Label5.Text & TextBox6.Text & Label6.Text & TextBox7.Text & Label7.Text & TextBox8.Text & Label8.Text & TextBox9.Text & Label9.Text & TextBox10.Text, False)

Comment: this is the rest of the code:
        RichTextBox1.SaveFile(dlg.FileName, RichTextBoxStreamType.RichText)
         End If
        Catch ex As Exception : End Try

Comment: Comments are not the best way to show your code. Just edit your question and add the code there. If you have problem formatting don't worry, someone will help

Answer (score 0):

What errors are you getting with this?  Why are you showing the FileSaveDialog if you are specifying a filename/path?  Why are you passing False into the WriteAllText method, instead of an Encoding type, like System.Text.Encoding.ASCII?

What if you did something like this instead?

```
Imports System.IO

Public Class Form1

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Try
        Dim myStream As StreamWriter
        Dim saveFileDialog1 As New SaveFileDialog()

        saveFileDialog1.Filter = "txt files (*.txt)|*.txt|All files (*.*)|*.*|Rich Text Files (.rtf)|.rtf"
        saveFileDialog1.FilterIndex = 1
        saveFileDialog1.RestoreDirectory = True

        If saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK Then
            myStream = New StreamWriter(saveFileDialog1.OpenFile())
            If (myStream IsNot Nothing) Then
                myStream.WriteLine(Me.Label1.Text & " " & Me.TextBox1.Text)
                'Additional lines, or however you want to format
                myStream.Close()
            End If
        End If

    Catch ex As Exception
        'Error handling
    End Try
End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: Woooow THANK YOU VERY MUCH it works :D :D :D appreciate it :')